# Mathematica refuses to plot this interesting graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to plot [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/788818/716778)  function $f$ which satisfies $f$ bounded, monotone, $C^\infty$, but $f'(x) \nrightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. I am running a linux computer with mathematica 12.3. My code is

```
h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[100]*Exp[-1/x^2 - 1/(x - 1)^2], 
0 < x < 1 }},0]

g[x_] := h[Floor[x]^2 (x - Floor[x])]

f[x_] := NIntegrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}]

Plot[f[x],{x,0,10}]
```

However the output is [image]

The Exp[100] is there because otherwise I get this error: [image: NIntegrate]

How can I fix this to see this beauty?

Comment: Works for me on Mac running Mathematica 13.0.

Comment: I get this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3t54.png) when I run your code. I am on v12.2.0 Win7-x64. Please restart Mathematica and try with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Without more information, my best guess is that you have not actually assigned `h`.

Comment: I get the same plot as user: `Syed` when I run your code. I am on v13.0. Win10-x64.

Comment: As a general rule, the arguments of functions that use numeric techniques should be restricted to numeric values, e.g., `f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}]`

Comment: Thanks its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in semicolons.  Works fine:

[image]